# PHP to HTML data passing and store

Tags: php, html

This is the PHP file that I've created so far. I'm trying to pass the information to the HTML and then save it in the HTML file then download it to the user

```
<?php
$uid = $_POST['gid'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST['gid'] != "") {
        header("Location:http://www.something.com/download.php?filename=ProjectA.html");
    } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Please enter your ID")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    WebID: <input type="text" value="" name="gid" id="gid"/></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Generate" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

So what i want to find out a way is that the WEB ID that they post in the form will be transferred to the ProjectA.html then will be downloaded..

Right now, my problem is passing data from PHP to HTML and store in the HTML.

```
<div id="" class="chaosnight">
    <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://www.something.com?u=['gid']"
    method="post">
```

I want the following line to change only. is the action

Comment: `WebID: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['gid'];?>" name ="gid" id="gid" />`

Comment: Do you mean you need to modify `ProjectA.html` so it contains the ID?

Comment: Show what `ProjectA.html` contains, and where you want to transfer the ID into it.

Comment: @Barmar , yeah .. Wait i'll post